Catalyst MacOS TestFlight subscriptions testing not working on Apple M2 Max
I am having problems with testing AppStore subscriptions on Apple M2 Max (macOS 15.0.1). It works as expected on iPhone, iPad and MacBook Pro (Intel chip, macOS 13.5.2)
I download the app from TestFlight and subscribe to one of the available subscription in the app:
func purchase(_ product: Product) async throws {
    let result = try await product.purchase()
    switch result {
    case .success(.verified(let transaction)):
        await transaction.finish()
    default:
        return
    }
}

Then I get this dialog (note that I am using Danish store already so the message should not appear):

When I press "Change Store" I constantly get this message:

I am pretty sure the AppStore on my machine and the app subscriptions are set up correctly otherwise it should not work as expected on the other devices.
Has any of you experienced similar challenges?

It seems to be a bug in test subscription handling on MacOS side. Production subscriptions work as expected after a release to AppStore.
